# How to configure NGINX to server only one static file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, nginx-config

Our Rails application is running on puma/nginx
below part of the NGINX configuration.

What's I'm trying to achieve is that when the request URL is http://example.com it will serve a static cached file from /public/cached_pages/index.html and in all other cases works like it is now so passing the request to rails/puma

```
upstream rails {
  server unix:///var/www/html/cms/shared/sockets/puma.sock;
}


   location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       add_header Cache-Control "public";
       expires 2d;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on; # Optional
       proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
       proxy_pass http://rails;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best solution, but did you try `try_files`? ([Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files))
In the rails context this is often used for assets, but might also work for your cache. The asset example would be something like this:

```
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app_production;
  location @app_production {
[...]
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://app_production;
```

The first line would need to be adjusted to your needs, but this might also work for your case.

Comment: This is not really the best option. You should match the exact path and then serve the exact file in the correct location using the location directive

Comment: I've updated my cache logic so to keep things simple i have about 50 routes and for a couple of them I have preprocessed cached HTML files i wanna serve.  so path / should serve index.html path /about should serve about.html and all other paths should proxy to rails. How to configure this?

Comment: I suggest making a dedicated rules for the `/` route, like suggested in another answer. Otherwise all requests have to probe for this special case. Additionally, something like `try_files $uri.html @app_name;` could work. It will try to find a file that matches the uri with a `.html` suffix and otherwise use the application. You could combine this with the first rule and have `try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html @app_name`, but that would create extra overhead. I didn't try out the suggestion myself, but conceptually it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `location` directive

```
  location = / {
    gzip_static on;
    root public/cached_pages
    index.html
  }
```

The `=` symbol will provide an exact match for the url, without the `=` symbol you will be matching any path whatsoever after the domain name. Next, switching gzip on will compress the file to reduce traffic bandwidth so that the index.html page will be zipped then setting the `root` directive to be the path to the file will enable nginx to find the file you want to serve, then the actual file itself should do the trick for you.

The root directive may need the full path to the folder rather than the relative public path, Obviously I do not know what that will be.